# Connecting to database using Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am trying to connect to my database using Spring JDBC

`Beans.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5434/lab1_aop" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="passw" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

The place I want to make the connection:

```
public class BookService { 
    private Connection connection;

    public BookService() {
         ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    }
}
```

I get these errors

```
The constructor ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String) refers to the missing type BeansException    BookService.java
The type org.springframework.beans.BeansException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your beans.xml in the /src folder ?.

Comment: some jars are missing. Check it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `spring-context` and `spring-beans` dependency for it, if you are using maven.

For better dependency management use `maven or gradle`.

add in `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>{spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>{spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have just converted it to a Maven project and added the dependency. So now I have to build the project?

Comment: Yes, now build project.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, you are missing some Spring Jars in your project! Use any standard Dependency management tool like Gradle, Maven or Ant to resolve your dependencies.

Here you will find an example of how to configure [Spring project using Gradle](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-mvc-web-project-example/).